# Java - fetch id Remove all characters from link

Tags: java, android

I have a string like this :

```
Domain.com/agahi/view/330/some+text+here
```

OR

```
Domain.com/agahi/view/330/
```

OR

```
Domain.com/agahi/view/330
```

Any way i have to fetch ID from this links ( `330` in this sample )

Notice : maybe `some+text+here` different .

how can i remove other characters ?

Comment: `String ID = yourString.replaceAll("Domain.com/agahi/view/(\\d+).*", "$1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will remove all alpha characters from your string (using a regular expression) and return only numeric characters:

```
String str = "Domain.com/agahi/view/330/some+text+here";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");

System.out.println(str);
```

Result:

```
330
```

Comment: Thank you but what about link like this : Domain.com/agahi/view/330/some+text+here+5 ?

Comment: In that instance (if you only want the 330 part of the string), you could split it using "/" as the delimiter:

    String str = "Domain.com/agahi/view/330/some+text+here+5";
    String[] id = str.split("/");
    String result = id[3];

If you still want to strip the id of alpha characters, you can continue to use:

    System.out.println(result.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));